# save the drag and drop the position in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I want to drag and drop the list in that time the position will save in database.......if i refresh that page the position will not be change......

in below i add the for that concept but the code in php i want how to do in rails...please help me..........

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery Sortable With AJAX &amp; MYSQL</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc4.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type="text/javascript">
  // When the document is ready set up our sortable with it's inherant function(s)
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test-list").sortable({
      handle : '.handle',
      update : function () {
        var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize');
        $("#info").load("process-sortable.php?"+order);
      }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<pre>

<div id="info">Waiting for update</div>
</pre>
<ul id="test-list">
  <li id="listItem_1">< alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item 1 </strong>with a link to <a href="http://www.google.co.uk/" rel="nofollow">Google</a></li>
  <li id="listItem_2"><i alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item 2</strong></li>
  <li id="listItem_3"><i" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item 3</strong></li>
  <li id="listItem_4">< alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item 4</strong></li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

in php.........

```
<?php
/* This is where you would inject your sql into the database 
   but we're just going to format it and send it back
*/

foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item) :
    $sql[] = "UPDATE `table` SET `position` = $position WHERE `id` = $item";
endforeach;

print_r ($sql);
?>
```

Comment: What does your Rails app look like so far?

Answer (score 3):

Here you have two really good examples:

http://awesomeful.net/posts/47-sortable-lists-with-jquery-in-rails

http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised

Comment: The awesomeful.net link appears to be 404.

Comment: You may want to look at this instead: http://webtempest.com/sortable-list-in-ruby-on-rails-3-almost-unobtrusive-jquery/

Comment: @tjeden the link you provided doesn't seem to be working.